# How to get an especific subdocument array MondoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a lot of documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "CEsSrYSHTiX",
    "flag_comentariosdesativados" : false,
    "lista_img" : [ 
        "118937998_638615533744934_2935884294206630517_n.jpg", 
        "118824457_348646689607320_152809910037509273_n.jpg"
    ],
    "campocr" : {
        "118937998_638615533744934_2935884294206630517_n" : {
            "textoextraido1" : "SA ADS\nÉ montagem vídeo que\nmostra Biden dormindo\nem entrevista ao vivo\n",
            "textoextraido2" : "É montagem vídeo que\nmostra Biden dormindo\nem entrevista ao vivo\n",
            "textoextraido3" : "Lupa\nO VERIFICAMOS\nÉ montagem vídeo que\nmostra Biden dormindo\nem entrevista ao vivo\n",
            "opcao" : 3
        },
        "118824457_348646689607320_152809910037509273_n" : {
            "textoextraido1" : "Acesse:\nlupa.news\nCompartilhe PP” Salve para\ncom um amigo mais tarde\n",
            "textoextraido2" : "C ANIS\nlupa.news\nCompartilhe PP” Salve para\ncom um amigo mais tarde\n",
            "textoextraido3" : "E A MTE\nlupa.news\n[E LU K Salve para\ncom um amigo mais tarde\n",
            "opcao" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to return only documents that have in the field campocr the value **118937998_638615533744934_2935884294206630517_n**

Comment: An exemple of what I would like: db.collection.find({campocr:'118937998_638615533744934_2935884294206630517_n'})

Answer (score 0):

Use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#embedded-documents) with [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/index.html), e.g. in MongoDB shell:

```
db.mycollection.find({'campocr.118937998_638615533744934_2935884294206630517_n': {'$exists': true}})
```

or, almost indentical in pymongo:

```
db.mycollection.find({'campocr.118937998_638615533744934_2935884294206630517_n': {'$exists': True}})
```

Comment: Are you using the shell or pymongo?

Comment: I'm using pymongo and I tried in the shell with robo3t

Comment: What is the name of the collection that has the data?

Comment: posts is the name

Answer (score 0):

Try the code sample as a standalond below. If this doesn't work, post a comment.

Make sure you are connected to the right server, port and database; it's easy to run commands against the wrong environment and it

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mycollection']

db.posts.insert_one(
{
    "_id" : "CEsSrYSHTiX",
    "flag_comentariosdesativados" : False,
    "lista_img" : [
        "118937998_638615533744934_2935884294206630517_n.jpg",
        "118824457_348646689607320_152809910037509273_n.jpg"
    ],
    "campocr" : {
        "118937998_638615533744934_2935884294206630517_n" : {
            "textoextraido1" : "SA ADS\nÉ montagem vídeo que\nmostra Biden dormindo\nem entrevista ao vivo\n",
            "textoextraido2" : "É montagem vídeo que\nmostra Biden dormindo\nem entrevista ao vivo\n",
            "textoextraido3" : "Lupa\nO VERIFICAMOS\nÉ montagem vídeo que\nmostra Biden dormindo\nem entrevista ao vivo\n",
            "opcao" : 3
        },
        "118824457_348646689607320_152809910037509273_n" : {
            "textoextraido1" : "Acesse:\nlupa.news\nCompartilhe PP” Salve para\ncom um amigo mais tarde\n",
            "textoextraido2" : "C ANIS\nlupa.news\nCompartilhe PP” Salve para\ncom um amigo mais tarde\n",
            "textoextraido3" : "E A MTE\nlupa.news\n[E LU K Salve para\ncom um amigo mais tarde\n",
            "opcao" : 1
        }
    }
})

x = db.posts.find({'campocr.118937998_638615533744934_2935884294206630517_n': {'$exists': True}})
print(list(x))
```